# Changing Server port on Angular 2

Tags: angular

i am trying to change the default "4200" port.

I tried adding the bs-config.json under src like this:

```
 {
  "port": 9002,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

but it did not work.
Moreover i searched in my whole project for port 4200 but i did not find the real configuration.

Please help me with this .

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

i added .ember-cli file in project root with custom port :

```
{
   "port": 9002
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what server software you're using, but based on your port and configuration it's most likely one of these:

**Angular2-cli**

If you are using something like

```
ng serve
```

You are using angular2-cli, and need to provide at port argument like so:

```
ng serve --port 9002
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage

**lite-server**

If you're using lite-server, your configuration looks correct, so ensure the configuration is loaded at startup. The console output normally says something like 'couldn't find bs-config.json, using default settings'

Answer (score 4):

#### angular cli provide default port 4200.for change the port number add serve json data into  "angular-cli.json"  file

```
 "defaults": {
"styleExt": "css",
"component": {},
"serve": {
  "port": 8080
}
```

}